# How to avoid node_modules binary incompatibilities when you run code cross platform from the same file share?

Tags: node.js, npm

Imagine that you have the folder mounted on multiple VMs which allows you to run the same code on multiple platforms (OS X, Windows, Linux).

All these are running from the same location but this also means that the `node_modules` created on one of the platforms will be visible on all of them and will break executions on the other ones.

I encountered the same problem while using Python virtual environments and the solution was to use the tox approach, to create virtual environment directories that do contain the platform in their name, like `.tox/python34-linux`.

Now, the question is how to solve the cross platform incompatibility with npm/node?

Comment: You can try this answer: [How to move npm node_modules folder cross-platform?](//stackoverflow.com/a/19290426/1397319)

Comment: @idbehold this would not work because you can have only a single symlink. Sadly it seems that node fully fails to provide a solution for this use-case. I have seen seem some bugs asking for custom folder name, closed and locked to prevent further comments on them.

Comment: Well you're essentially asking how to make some binaries which were compiled on one platform to work on another. Which just isn't possible. Hence the compilation step. You need to rebuild on each different platform.

Comment: Not really, I am asking how do I solve the problem. With Python virtual environments it worked perfectly, with node, I have some doubts.